# OpenCV viz library questions

Tags: opencv, 3d, vision

I have the following problem: I have the set of points of a 3D sphere. Is it possible to represent it in 3D using viz?

I don't find so much material about this library.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a set of points in 3D space (x,y,z for every point) and color values for them (r,g,b for every point). You can represent them via opencv Viz.

You can find a tutorial [HERE](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d72/tutorial_transformations.html)